# Globals declared in h file and access to them

Tags: c, header, extern, global

Just a simple question for understanding:

variable `extern int x_glob` is declared in header `glob.h`.

so in every c file that contains functions declared in `glob.h` using this variable I have to define it agin like this:

```
extern void func_1( void )
{
  int x_glob;

  glob_x++;
  return();
}
```

Is that correct?

If I leave off the extern word on the declaration of `x_glob` in `glob.h`, I don't need the definition.

Why not leaving away the `extern` word in the header file?

Maybe this question sounds stupid - my goal is to get a better structure into
my programming as the projects grow.

Comment: If you want better structuring in your code, start with avoding globals as far as as possible in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is wrong. With `int x_glob` inside a function you declare a local, automatic variable. This overrides any global variable.

But in precisely one .c file you must declare the global variable:

```
// main.c

int x_glob;
```

This creates one variable that can now be used by all modules. The `extern` version of the variable only tells the compiler when compiling the other modules that somewhere there exists this variable and it will be found upon linking the modules into the excutable.

Personally I prefer the following set-up:

```
// glob.h
#ifndef EXTERN
#define EXTERN extern
#endif
EXTERN int x_glob;

// module.c
#include "glob.h"

// main.c
#define EXTERN
#include "glob.h"
```

In all modules `x_glob` will be known as `extern` and in main it will not be extern and so will declare the storage for the global variable.

Comment: "*at least*" -> "*exactly*". Otherwise, linking should fail for multiple definitions.

Comment: Thank you my friend - there were too many trees to see the forest

Comment: @Dagute, then click the button on the left to accept my answer. Glad to have been of help.

Comment: @paul - which button - sorry but i am new to this forum

Comment: The one that now says "3" with an up and down button, on the left. Click on the "3" to accept the answer. This is how you indicate the answer solved or helped you solve your problem.